# Select some SQL rows that contains a specific INT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with my database. I don't know how to find the SQL rows containing a specific INT. I have a list of news, and if this news is publish, the INT is 1. This is my code:

```
$base = $db->query('SELECT id, title, image, content, date, slug, publish FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC');

while($row = $base->fetch()) {

    if ($row['publish'] == 1) {

        /* NEWS */

    }

}
```

Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: Add WHERE column_name = 1 before the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `where` publish=1 in MySQL query :-

```
$base = $db->query('SELECT id, title, image, content, date, slug, 
publish FROM articles where publish=1 ORDER BY id DESC');
```

Than no need of this condition :-

```
if ($row['publish'] == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to check in `while()`, add the condition in `select` only.

```
$base = $db->query('SELECT id, title, image, content, date, slug, publish 
FROM articles WHERE publish = 1 ORDER BY id DESC');
              ^                ^
```